# Remove/hide particular Anchor Categories in category properties

Tags: magento-1.8, category

I am new to magento, I have created the Anchor Categories by referring [magentocommerce](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/anchor-categories), and it's working fine now the question is I want to Remove/Hide particular Anchor Categorie how can I do?

Example: I have 2 Anchor Categories like Color & Price. I want to hide/remove Color how can I Do this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: as your mention url that color and price is not a category it's product attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide the below Color and price Follow below steps.

`Step1` : Go to back end. Open catalog >> Attributes >> Manage Attributes.

`Step2` : search color and open color in edit mode.

`step3` : search `Use In Layered Navigation` and select `No`.

`Step4` : Refresh your cache.

Comment: you are welcome :)